# JQuery parent->child selection

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a group of textboxes that I want to perform some actions upon on the client side. I want to use JQuery to do this. I simplified example of my problem is as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Don'tSelectME_1" runat="server" />
 <table id = "outer_1">
  <table id="inner_1">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="SelectME_1" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="SelectME_2" runat="server" />
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="inner_2">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="SelectME_3" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="SelectME_4" runat="server" />
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</table>
```

Without a discussion of nested tables (would of rather used div's personally) I want to select the textboxes inside the 2 nested tables.

I am trying to select using something like $('table[id="outer_1"] > table > tr > td >input) to grab all the textbox inputs. Not working however, anyone have any ideas? I am thinking that perhaps the ">" selector can only be used once in the selector. Thanks all in advance

Comment: The `>` selector means immediate child, if this is not guaranteed, leave it out.  Not having, leaving just a space, means a child at any depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always wonder why people use `.find()` when it can just be put into the selector directly and let the selector engine decide how to handle it in one function call instead of two.

```
$("#outer_1 input")
```

will get all input tags in the specified table.  To explain, this means to find the object with ID `#outer_1` and then search for all decendants that have a tag type of `input`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table#outer_1').find('input');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/WXVbF/2/) is a **live working example**, I also fixed your invalid table html...

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because

- (almost) all browsers insert a `tbody` tag:

  `$('#outer_1 > tbody table > tbody > tr > td >input')`
- Your HTML markup for table is not correct.

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/6vQ9p/

However, you can simplify your selectors by saying:

`$('#outer_1 #inner_1 :input')` (if you must use the outer table)

or `$('#inner_1 :input')` (since you've id on inner table too)

http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/6vQ9p/1/

Comment: @Blowsie, no this IS true actually. Most browsers do add the `<tbody>` tag whether or not you supply one in your source.

Comment: How did you load up my HTML into fiddle like that?

Comment: @R-Tard - Thanks for that , its amazing the small things you can miss even after so many years.. removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its far more flexible

```
$("table").find("input")
```

or for the child tables only

```
$("table table").find("input")
```

Answer (score 0):

<table> is not a valid (direct) child of <table> (only <thead>, <tbody>, <tfoot> and <tr>), different browsers will handle this error differently, and some will fill in the missing elements for you, so a correct selector would be something like: `#outer_1 > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > input` for some browsers or maybe `#outer_1 > table > tr > td > table > tr > td > input` for others.

My suggestion would be to first, like you say, use div(s) for container(s) rather than a  element with no row or cell tags, and if you don't mind selecting all descendant  elements of #outer_1 your selector could be simplified to:

```
$('#outer_1 input')
```

As a side note, could you post the generated HTML, rather than the ASP code?